# Make some submodules optional in git

Tags: git, git-submodules

We have a git repo that is serving multiple projects/targets.
In addition there are 3 submodules for separately developed modules that are referenced and pulled into the workspace.

Are are going to have a 4th repo for a module that will be needed only for a specific project and only specific engineers have permissions to access it.
Is there any way to make this 4th submodule optional or it's all-or-nothing?

Thanks a lot,

Guy.

Comment: How would an "optional" submodule differ from a "not-optional" one? What behaviour would be different in your idea?

Comment: Few alternatives can work for me (and maybe more that I'm missing):
* By default an optional submodule won't be cloned, but will have to be explicitly "enabled", or the other way around - there will be a way to mask it.
* If the user doesn't have permissions for an optional submodule, the overall recursive operation won't fail, but maybe there will be just a warning printed.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question: What is an "optional submodule" and what would be the difference to a "normal" one? What, in your opinion makes a submodule optional or not optional?

Comment: I will clarify my clarification - I'm looking for a way to avoid a failure of the overall recursive operations when a user doesn't have permissions to (or just doesn't need) a submodule

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like following in your `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "secrets"]
    path = secrets
    url = ./secrets
```

Then, after checkout, you can clone the optional repositories like:

```
rm -rf secrets
git clone git://... secrets
```